# Displaying web scraped data in Tkinter GUI in Python

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, web-scraping, python-requests

I am scraping (requests and beautiful soup) and storing the data in csv file and reading the csv file (pandas) to display in GUI (tkinter).
The problem I am facing is that the currently scraped data is not getting displayed, its displaying the **previously scraped data** when the program was last run.

On the first GUI page (`tk.Frame`), on pressing the submit button, the data is scraped and is stored in a CSV file after which the second GUI page (`tk.Frame`) is called.
This is how the tkinter code looks like -

```
class FirstPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    submitButton = tk.Button(
      self,
      text="Display data",
      command=self.foo,
    )

  def foo(self):
    self.scrapeData()
    self.storeToCsv()
    self.controller.callNextFrame()
```

The scraped data stored in the CSV file is then displayed in a tkinter `OptionMenu` drop-down menu in the second page.

```
class SecondPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
    data = pandas.read_csv()
    menuData = data.items.tolist()
    menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, menuData)
```

I thought of moving the read CSV part to `foo()`, but the result is the same.
Will asynchronous programming solve the issue?